# How do I edit field types with managed schemas in solr 6+

Tags: solr, lucene, schema

I am migrating from solr 4 to solr 6.
Solr is using my old schema.xml to create a new managed_schema.
Using the solr admin website ui, I can edit the managed schema.
However, the field_types are not editable. I can't figure out how to change the analyzers.

I can edit it in my schema.xml and then delete managed_schema, causing it to rebuild the managed_schema. But that is tedious.

I know I can change solrconfig to use the schema.xml instead of the managed-schema. But what I would prefer to do is to migrate to the managed schema. I just need to be able to change the analyzers.

So my question is: how do I make changes to the analyzers inside of a field_type using the managed-schema UI (or another method is ok too if it is easy)[image]?

Answer (score 3):

You **can** edit managed_schema and then reload the core. You just should not be editing managed_schema by hand as you are changing it via UI as that will override hand changes.

Comment: Is this the preferred way of handling this? Their docs seem to imply that editing the file is not the route to go

Comment: The preferred way is via API. But not API has Admin UI implementation. So, you can do it with HTTP calls directly. Or you can edit it by hand as in the answer. Notice that if you run SolrCloud, your managed_schema is not actually on disk. So, you need to download/edit/re-upload. Again, not the best option, but a valid one.